# Menu Mobile Fixed Zoom, meta or css?

Tags: css, mobile, zooming, meta

**tl:dr; I can't zoom freely on a mobile device throughout each page on http://lillhammarandfriends.com/**

I am using an iPhone5.

While on the homepage, I try to zoom into the center of the menu, but it will only let me zoom into the top left of the page. The menu is only at the bottom on the *homepage*.

The Menu is at the top on all other interior pages like http://lillhammarandfriends.com/brand.html and it still is only zooms into the top left, any solutions to this problem stackOVO?!